Получение номеров из списка профилей водителей Яндекс
Работаю с официальным API Яндекс Диспетчерской для таксопарков и не могу понять, почему нет данных о номерах водителей. Пишу в соответствии с документацией https://fleet.taxi.yandex.ru/docs/api/reference/ContractorProfiles/v1_parks_driver-profiles_list_post.html. Делаю POST запрос через Postman на API:
https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/driver-profiles/list
в headers использую все заголовки по документации:
X-Client-ID и X-Api-Key.
body:
{
    "fields": {
        "driver_profile": [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "middle_name",
            "phones"
        ]
    },
    "limit": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "sort_order": [
        {
            "direction": "asc",
            "field": "driver_profile.created_date"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "park": {
            "id": "parkId"
        },
        "work_status": [
            "working"
        ]
    }
}

и получаю вот такой ответ:
"driver_profiles": [
        {
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "balance": "400.0000",
                    "balance_limit": "5.0000",
                    "currency": "RUB",
                    "id": "accountID",
                    "type": "current",
                    "last_transaction_date": "2024-05-01T14:17:31.434297+00:00"
                }
            ],
            "car": {
                "amenities": [],
                "brand": "Hyundai",
                "callsign": "COURIER2c24597e0ef34f2eae8a06773ade2ac2",
                "category": [
                    "courier"
                ],
                "color": "Белый",
                "id": "f6bb258cd43a7062b865d4af274e46ba",
                "model": "Solaris",
                "normalized_number": "C0URIER2C24597E0EF34F2EAE8A06773ADE2AC2",
                "number": "COURIER2c24597e0ef34f2eae8a06773ade2ac2",
                "status": "working",
                "year": 1980
            },
            "driver_profile": {
                "first_name": "Тест2",
                "id": "driverID",
                "last_name": "Тест2",
                "middle_name": "Тест2",
                "phones": []
            },
            "current_status": {
                "status": "offline"
            }
        }
    ],

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этим

номер телефона или номер авто?

Именно номер телефона
